# Update text field values in multiple tabs with single button

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I have 6 tabs in my application.
Each tab has a text field.
There is one button in the sixth tab, which when pressed, should reset the text fields in all the other 5 tabs to blank.

I am unable to figure out any direction in which I should look.

I am pretty new to Xcode, so please pardon my ignorance on this topic.

One thing I have tried so far is to set global variable.
When I press the button, I update the global variable to ""
But then I go to the other tabs, the value has not been updated.

My understanding is that I an not writing the code in the right place.
Currently, I have written this code in viewDidLoad function of each tab's viewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    telephone.text = ViewLine.GlobalVariable.phone1
    timerData.text = ViewLine.GlobalVariable.concept1
}
```

phone1 and concept1 are my global variables.

Would anyone be able to suggest where should I write this code? or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Post your full code so that we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write code in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    telephone.text = ViewLine.GlobalVariable.phone1
    timerData.text = ViewLine.GlobalVariable.concept1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is the first 5 view controllers to **react** to a tap on a button in the 6th view controller.
In that case - don't use global variables.

Use notifications: 
When the button did tap, send a notification. The first 5 view controllers should subscribe to this notification channel. When each of the first 5 view controllers receive a notification they should change the text to "".

Here is a link on notifications:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/160653/design-patterns-ios-using-swift-part-22